# RoR: Model validation question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a basic ActiveRecord model in which i have two fields that i would like to validate. The requirement is that at least one of the fields must have a value. Both can have values, but at least one needs a value.

How do i express this with

```
validates_presence_of
```

statements? For example:

```
validates_presence_of :main_file
validates_presence_of :alt_file
```

i don't want an error to be generated if only one of them is empty, only if both are empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
validates_presence_of :main_file, :if => Proc.new { |p| p.alt_file.blank? }
validates_presence_of :alt_file, :if => Proc.new { |p| p.main_file.blank? }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to `blank?` instead of `nil?`?

Answer (score 3):

changing .nil? to .blank? does the trick!